# Ubuntu Server 16.04 openstack mitaka installation juju error

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install Openstack (Mitaka) on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server. During `conjure-up openstack` I ran into the following error:

```
traceback into juju.py:
    line 96:
    password = account['users'][current_user]['password']
```

`current_user` is `None`.. which explains the TypeError we get from python

Addition: I traced back the problem. It has emerged after the last update/upgrade of ubuntu server with the single node installation of openstack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The same error here... I've figured out that accounts.yaml file is in wrong format... I'm not sure how it should look like exactly, but this works for me:

`patok@openstack01:~/.local/share/juju$ cat accounts.yaml 
controllers:
  connor:
    accounts: 
      user: admin@local
      password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    current-account: 
      user: admin@local
      password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

... but now I've run into an another problem - cannot select anything else then "Connect to an existing MAAS".

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I found that upgrading juju and conjure-up worked. (I'm on Xenial release.)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:conjure-up/next
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:juju/devel
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```